# why would /etc/init.d/mysql run the wrong upstart job?

Tags: mysql, upstart

**update:** `/lib/init/upstart-job` has been replaced with the MongoDB init script.

For some reason, `/etc/init.d/mysql start|stop|restart|status` <sup><sub>(`/etc/init.d/mysql` is simply a symlink to `/lib/init/upstart-job`)</sub></sup> is affecting my MongoDB install, not my MySQL install. `service start|stop|restart|status mysql` works as you'd expect.

An example:

```
root@score:~# /etc/init.d/mysql status
 * Checking status of database MongoDB
   ...fail!
root@score:~#
```

What could cause this, and how can I fix it?

**Scripts:**

- `/lib/init/upstart-job`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/517647/
- `/etc/init/mysql.conf`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/517648/
- `/etc/init/mongodb.conf`: http://paste.ubuntu.com/517649/

Comment: Please can you post the contents of /etc/init.d/mysql?

Comment: `/etc/init.d/mysql` is a symlink to `/lib/init/upstart-job`.

Comment: @Jorge Castro Done.

Comment: You should also try `status mysql`.

Comment: Oh, and check the contents of `/etc/init/mysql` and (if that exists) `/etc/init/mongodb`

Comment: @JanC `status mysql` works as expected (correct process ID etc.). The `/etc/init` files are as you'd expect, too - respectively correct commands in each one.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running? Could you also please post the three files involved `/lib/init/upstart-job`, `/etc/init/mysql` and `/etc/init/mongodb`? (Consider using http://paste.ubuntu.com/)  Although they seem to be as we'd expect, chance is that they are not -- otherwise you wouldn't be asking this question ;-)

Comment: Er... I meant `/etc/init/mysql.conf` and `/etc/init/mongodb.conf`

Comment: @Riccardo Murri Added, cheers.

Comment: Thanks for pasting that - it looks like /lib/init/upstart-job now has the contents of what was /etc/init.d/mongodb-server

Comment: Indeed it does. Any idea on how to fix that? Post your comment as an answer and I'll give ya the bonus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct contents of /lib/init/upstart-job for lucid or maverick are http://paste.ubuntu.com/517673/
Please triple-check that it is a regular file before editing this, and not a symlink (in case the symlink in in the wrong direction). Since this file is used for starting many core services, you do not want to have it broken further, and should check carefully before rebooting.
At this stage, I'm not sure how it could have the different contents unless there was some manual intervention to change it. The package in maverick appears to contain the correct symlink.

Comment: Thanks! Will award the bounty in 20 hours when it lets me. I'm using MongoDB's package repo for this. Very odd - I'm about 99% sure I didn't do anything manually to do this.

Comment: I'll have to check that one out - I was looking at the mongodb packages in lucid & maverick & hadn't spotted a problem in the postinst or other packaging there